# entity framework updates are silently ignored

Tags: entity-framework

I retrieve a stay via a WCF service and pass it to the front end.  A user updates the data on that object and then its passed back to the WCF service.

The following code works fine to add new stays, but it silently ignores updates.  What am I missing?

public void UpdateStay(ResidentDataTypes.Stay stay)

```
    {
        using (ResidentDataTypes.ResidentEntities entity = new ResidentDataTypes.ResidentEntities())
        {
            if (stay.StayId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                entity.Stay.AddObject(stay);
            }
            else
            {
                entity.Stay.ApplyChanges(stay);
            }
            entity.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When your objects serialized from WCF they are in Detached state and EF will not generate update statement for them. You have 2 options:

1. Get the same object from the DB and then do a [*ObjectSet.ApplyCurrentValues:*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466205.aspx)

```
using (ResidentDataTypes.ResidentEntities context = new 
                                            ResidentDataTypes.ResidentEntities())
{
    if (stay.StayId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        context.Stay.AddObject(stay);
    }
    else
    {
         // Fetch the Stay object into the cache:
         context.Stay.First(s => s.StayId == stay.StayId);

         // Now ApplyCurrentValues from the stay object coming from WCF:
         context.Stay.ApplyCurrentValues(stay);
    }
    entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

2.Manually change the Detached state to Modified:

```
using (ResidentDataTypes.ResidentEntities context = new 
                                            ResidentDataTypes.ResidentEntities())
{
    if (stay.StayId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        context.Stay.AddObject(stay);
    }
    else
    {        
        // Attach the stay object coming from WCF to ObjectContext:
        context.Stay.Attach(stay);

        // The attached object is going into Unchanged mode after attaching 
       // so we need to change the state to Modified:
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(stay, EntityState.Modified);
     }
     entity.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: OK, that works for the 'Stay'.  So if I have updates in child objects as well, do I have to load all those too?

Comment: Yes. *ApplyCurrentValues* does only work with the scalar properties on a single entity and will not take into account any child object your entity might have.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to attach your entity to your context with something like

```
entity.Attach(stay)
```